# When call api using .net core code Vietnamese char goes wrong

Tags: c#, json, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Below, I have code in .NET core azure function app which works well.

I called one API and pass input data but on other side when I check my data which is inserted from API it has wrong Vietnamese char.

```cs
string APIURL = "https://mydemo.com/insertcustomer.asmx";
string xmlHeader = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap = \"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><ImportCustomer xmlns= \"http://tempuri.org/\">";
        string xmlRequestBody = xmlHeader + "<xmlCstData><![CDATA[<Invoices><AmountInWords>KHÔNG VIỆT NAM ĐỒNG</AmountInWords></Invoices>]]></xmlCstData></ImportCustomer></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> callAPI(string APIURL, string xmlRequestBody, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiUserName + ":" + apiPassword);
        Function1.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        Function1.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, APIURL);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(xmlRequestBody);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "utf-8"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await Function1.httpClient.PostAsync(APIURL, httpContent);

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        log.LogError("Error: " + exception.ToString());
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

The input value for `AmountInWords = KHÔNG VIỆT NAM ĐỒNG` but after inserting into portal, I can see `AmountInWords = KHễNG VIỆT NAM ĐỒNG`. The only wrong character is `ễ`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be stemming from character encoding. Did you try changing this line

```
httpContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "utf-8"));
```

to this?

```
httpContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "unicode"));
```

Comment: let me try this solution thanks in advance i will comment soon :)